# CSS in a Flex 3 Library

Tags: css, apache-flex

I've made a library in flex with different components and my CSS I want to use in different projects (the goal of a library....).
BUT even if I can use my components, I can't use my CSS file which is in the library.
When I try `<mx:Style source="assets/style.css" />`, it wasn't found :(

So, how I should do to have a CSS file in my library which can be use in a project  ??

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project in the package explorer and locate your CSS file. It should show up automatically if your source path is set up correctly and the asset is descendant of that directory. Then just make sure the checkbox next to the CSS file name is checked.

Comment: Ok, I've checked the CSS File in the tab 'Asset' in the Flex Library Path properties.  
It works when I add the library as a project in my Library path, but doesn't when add as a swc (which is the way I want to attach my library).